# AWS hmac encryption discrepencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, sha256, hmac

I am facing a very strange issue and have spent 3+ days on it. I am going through AWS's signing request version 4 documentation and am investigating their HMAC signing process.

I am using node-forge to calculate an HMAC-sha256 based upon a given string and key, using this AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html

These are the exact same strings as the documentation encoded as the documentation says to UTF-8:

```
const hash_type = 'sha256';
const hmac = forge.hmac.create();
const key = forge.util.encodeUtf8('c4afb1cc5771d871763a393e44b703571b55cc28424d1a5e86da6ed3c154a4b9');
const string = forge.util.encodeUtf8('AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n' +
  '20150830T123600Z\n' +
  '20150830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request\n' +
  'f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59');
hmac.start('sha256', key);
hmac.update(string);
console.log('SIGNATURE: ' +  hmac.digest().toHex());
```

My function, along with every single HMAC calculator I use online give the caluclated hash as `fe52b221b5173b501c9863cec59554224072ca34c1c827ec5fb8a257f97637b1`

Even the AWS Code provided by them for both javascript and python derived the same values and calculates the same hash as I received.

However, according to the documentation in their doc's, it should be:
`5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7`

I have tried over 10+ calculators that all return the same value I received until I found 1 online calculator, only 1, that calculates the same as amazon at https://cryptii.com/hmac

I know HMAC is a mathematical function that is absolute, the same input will give the same output, which means that the input is different or that it is transformed along the way in a way that is abstracted from me.

Any tips?

Comment: Try `const key = forge.util.hexToBytes('c4afb1cc5771d871763a393e44b703571b55cc28424d1a5e86da6ed3c154a4b9');`.  The signing key is a binary blob.  It can't be utf8.  This is the hex representation of that key.

Comment: This was it I can't believe it after 3 days you saved me, you are my hero. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot. You have helped me after running to this same problem 3 years later!

Dallin - Thank you for your initial question with foresight to add the hash codes.